# React Draft wysiwyg won't load css styles

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, rollupjs

I am developing a React Library created with [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library).
Works well and now I want to implement a html text editor. I chose [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/) for this.
I encountered 2 problems:

1. Adding `Editor` and `EditorState` to my component:

   `import {Editor} from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
   import {EditorState} from 'draft-js';`

Rollup couldn't resolve the necessary Editor and EditorState classes. It was giving the error 'name-is-not-exported-by-module'. After [searching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nhz.io/rollup-plugin-commonjs) and trying, I resolved this problem by adding these lines to rollup.config.js:

```
commonjs({
        namedExports: {
            'node_modules/draft-js/lib/Draft.js': [ 'EditorState' ],
            'react-draft-wysiwyg': [ 'Editor' ]

        }
    }),
```

Now the editor shows up.

2. Loading css

`import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';`

Styles won't load either but this time, no warning is shown in the console, they just don't load.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Where is the code example of that editor? How do you use that css file in your code?

Comment: The css file is inside the node_modules folder. Is is inserted using
`import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css`
When I link the css in my index.html page, all works well.
It has to be a babel or a rollup config issue.

Comment: what do you mean by 'example of that editor'?

Comment: By that, I mean show us the code example where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer sooner but I had no time to upload a example. It works now. Is it possible that at first, the css file wasn't found because the dist folder still had to be created? Would it have been created after I did a `yarn build`?

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Are you seeing something like this? 
Can you try this and see, **import '../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';**

I am using the same editor, but never faced any of the above issues. Are you sure it is installed correctly? Because the first issue you faced looks like that.

Comment: It's weird, I first solved my problem by copying the css file in my public folder and added a link tag to include it in the page. This, obviously, worked. Before I had indeed the output you show. Now, to check your solution, I removed the css file and the link tag but everything showed up correct.Suddenly, my import statement `import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css'` worked fine. I'm glad it works ok now but I feel frustrated that I don't know exactly what made it working :( Thx for the advice though

Comment: Mine looks like this but its not fixed

Comment: It should fix it @CarterCole. Are you importing `*.css`from right place?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but for those who are using NextJs, and are getting this problem, adding this import  `@import '~react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';`  to the global CSS (or SASS, LESS ) file should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your imports should be similar something like the following

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js'
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg'
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css'
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css'
```

and the function body and return should be:

```
const Editor = () => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const onEditorStateChange = (state) => {
        setEditorState(state);
        let text = state.getCurrentContent().getPlainText('\u0001');
        setText(text);
    };

    return ( <Editor editorState={editorState} onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange} />
    );
};
```